# Buttons or list?

Tags: android-listview, android, android-button

I'm writing an application that will record the voice. It will have 4 categories: Words, Sentences, Paragraph and Story. Word category consists of list of words that suppose to be recorded, Sentence and Paragraph will work the same way. Story will allow user to record his own story. My question is what is the best way to implement it? Should I use 4 buttons represented the 4 categories or create a listView? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Its depends on your client requirement. But its obvious to use button than a List. A common approach to create 4 buttons rather than listview

Comment: Only advantage of a list would be the possibility to save the users preference. But since there are only 4 choices/buttons there's no real value in that. As a user I'd prefer buttons.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Thanks so much for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app will only do that, then I suggest you to implement a [Dashboard](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/02/ui-design-pattern-dashboard.html). This is simple and efficient, with a very fast access to main functionalities.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did not know about Dashboard but it seems to be interesting. I forgot to add that I work on Android 2.3 Does it support Dashboard? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcinS. The Dashboard is just a concept. It's in fact a layout with some buttons.